# Как сгенерировать свойства файла

Tags: c#

Как сгенерировать (через button) свойства файла ( рандомно ) в поля текстбоксов ( скрин)

Что нужно сгенерировать

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("[TITLE]")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("[DESCRIPTION]")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("[COPYRIGHT]")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("[VERSION]")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("[FILE-VERSION]")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("[COMPANY]")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("[PRODUCT]")]
```

Вообщем суть что нужно при нажатие на кнопку сгенерировать разные AssemblyText[TEXT] в текстбокс в рандомном порядке!

Comment: Запишите в `array` или `List<string>` эти строки и перетасуйте их на основании случайно выбранного индекса, а потом отобразите их в текстбоксе.

Comment: А можно пример?

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Random rng = new Random();  

public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
       n--;  
    int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
    T value = list[k];  
    list[k] = list[n];  
    list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
```

Использование (вставить в обработчик нажатия кнопки)

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();
myStrings.Add(@"[assembly: AssemblyTitle("[TITLE]")]"); //аналогично др.строками набъете

myStrings.Shuffle(); //перетасовываем

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var item in myStrings)
{
    builder.Append(item);
    builder.Append(" ");
}
this.MyTextBox.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Не подскажите как можно сгенерировать эту строчку?!                         string[] sv = { "Windows", "Microsoft", "ZoooFMega"};

Comment: @ArteS не понял вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо за пример выше, хочу узнать можно ли поочередно в текстбокс при генерации вызвать текст из string[] sv ??! Вот так более понятнее будет я думаю)

Comment: По вашему примеру выше, использую всё это в UserControl'e , мне выдаёт ошибку: Ошибка 1 Метод расширения должен быть определен в статическом классе, не являющимся универсальным

Comment: Можно ли Ваш пример занести в класс и вызывать его уже от туда?

Comment: Если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то галку поставьте. А поочередное добавление реализуется с помощью `TextBox.Text += очередная порция данных`

Comment: @ArteS верхний блок должен быть в отдельном статичном классе, создайте его и скопируйте туда этот блок кода

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48009/discussion-between-artes-and-bulson).